# Is SF Compact the default system font in WatchOS2?

Tags: ios, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I just wanted to know if the system font for watchOS 2 is San Francisco Compact.

I know that if we want to download the font, we need to have a developer account and agree to the licensing agreement terms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  This is mentioned [in](https://developer.apple.com/watch/human-interface-guidelines/typography/) [several](https://developer.apple.com/watchos/download/) [places](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/) on Apple's website.

> The San Francisco Compact typeface is the system font for watchOS. These fonts were designed specifically for legibility on small screens.

and

> The SF Compact font is the system font on Apple Watch. There are two variants of this font: SF Compact Text and SF Compact Display. When you specify the system font for text in labels and other system interface elements, Apple Watch automatically applies the most appropriate version of the font based on the point size. It also switches fonts automatically as needed.