# ".SFUIText-Regular" doesn't exist on watchOS

Tags: html, ios, swift, watchkit, watchos-2

I am creating an app for Apple Watch and iOS. I have HTML data which I transform into NSAttributedString to display in a UITextView (on iOS). I also want to send it to the watch to display it in a label.

Everything looks ok in the text view (e.g., correct background color). On the watch, it only displays the text (without any colors) and returns this error:

```
app-Watch Extension[2994:212335] CoreText: PostScript name ".SFUIText-Regular" does not exist.
```

Here is my code:

```
let mutAttText = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString: self.textView.attributedText)
let attributedOptions : [String: AnyObject] = [
    NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
    NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding
]
var data: NSData = NSData()
do {
data = try mutAttText.dataFromRange(NSMakeRange(0, mutAttText.length), documentAttributes: attributedOptions)
} catch {

}


let htmlString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(htmlString)

var attrStr = NSMutableAttributedString()
do {
    attrStr = try NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options: [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType], documentAttributes: nil)
    attrStr.enumerateAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, inRange: NSMakeRange(0, attrStr.length), options: NSAttributedStringEnumerationOptions.LongestEffectiveRangeNotRequired, usingBlock: { (attribute: AnyObject?, range: NSRange, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in
        if let attributeFont = attribute as? UIFont {
            let newPointSize = CGFloat(15)
            let scaledFont = UIFont(descriptor: attributeFont.fontDescriptor(), size: newPointSize)
            attrStr.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: scaledFont, range: range)
        }
    })
    self.textView.attributedText = attrStr
    self.sendText(attrStr)
}
catch {
    print("error creating attributed string")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although iOS and watchOS both use the San Francisco font, the fonts do differ between platforms:

- iOS, tvOS, and OS X uses San Francisco (SF-UI).
- watchOS uses San Francisco Compact (SF-Compact).

It looks like you're trying to scale the pointSize of an iOS system font, but `.SFUIText-Regular` doesn't exist on watchOS.

You also may want to use `systemFontOfSize:` instead of trying to scale the point size of a named font, since there are different (text and display) versions depending on point size. This will allow the system to [automatically select the appropriate (text or display) variant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35077286/4151918) for that point size.